# How to use openframworks's ofBuffer to append values to an XML?

Tags: c++, xml, file-io, openframeworks

I'm trying to append nodes to an xml file and close the stream at a certain event.
I've started with the xmlSettingsExample, but the example saves everything once on key press.

I would like to do something like:

- setup xml (add root note, push tag)
- open file to write xml to
- append xml 'header'
- while updating append nodes send to a buffer and append to file
- on app exit pop tag, close file

I've started like so:

```
xmlFile.open(ofToDataPath("stream.xml"), ofFile::Append, false);
```

I imagine on update, after updating my xml I'd do:

```
xmlFile.writeFromBuffer(xmlBuffer);
```

and on app exit:

```
xmlFile.close();
```

My main question is how do plug my xml object into the xmlBuffer (which is an ofBuffer) ?
I imagine I use the set() method, but not sure how to convert the ofxXmlSettings object to the type accepted by ofBuffer's set(). Also, is this approach correct or should I be handling this in a different way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment I've opted for using ofFile to append contents to:

```
//set this up once
ofFile file;
file.open("file.xml", ofFile::Append);
//update contents multiple times
file << "<data>\n";
//close when done
file.close();
```